# Renamed Windows 2008 R2 domain ---WindowsXP client could not updated with new Domain name

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have renamed Windows Server 2008 R2 with all the steps using rendom,repadmin,gpupdate and successfully updated domain. My windows vista and above client got updated new domain when restarted.
The help taken is from site
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwXyi1_UDWo

But problem is with windows XP clients, they could not get new domain logon screen ans showing old domain name in logon screen..

Kindly anyone help me.........

Comment: Have you rebooted *twice*?

Comment: yes.. sir i have restarted 3 times clients and server as well

Comment: What happens when you try to log on via one of these clients? Do you get a trust relationship error?

Comment: the error while logon to old domain in windows XP client is "The system cannot log you on now because the domain xyx.local ( old domain name ) is not available..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's quite common for XP machines to not pick up the change properly, even after a number of reboots.

You could manually rejoin the computers to the domain, or if that isn't practical you could script the process by using [netdom](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772217.aspx), which is available as part of the Remote Server Administration Tools and should automatically be installed on your DCs. The [NETDOM move](http://ss64.com/nt/netdom-move.html) command looks like your best bet.

There's no reason why you couldn't use a "for" loop in a batch command to run NETDOM against a list of client PCs held in a text file.